# Why i am getting "exception caught by widgets library" error after enabling null safety?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am creating a basic quotes app for my practice project.Everything were fine when i hot restart/ relod or restart the app..But Few moment ago,when i enabled null safety,though it didnt show any error in the dart analysis,but while running it got stuck to one page.So when inspected in the run section,i found so many red line indicating error.First one says, **"Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?"** though i have opened hive box in the main function. It also says, **"The relevant error-causing widget was:"**...indicates to a page with just a page-view widget.I am literally stuck.What i can i do mow..I am providing the code below where the computer says the problem might have occuured

```
 class OverviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 const OverviewScreen({key, Key,}) : super(key: key);
 @override
_OverviewScreenState createState() => _OverviewScreenState();
}

class _OverviewScreenState extends State<OverviewScreen> {
PageController pageController =PageController(initialPage: 0);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home:Scaffold(
    drawer:NavigationDrawerWidget() ,
    extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hu   R   Rehman",
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "MonteCarlo"),),
        centerTitle: true,


      shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(16))
      ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,

    ),
    body:Center(
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          PageView(
            controller:pageController,
            children: [
              Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [



                  Image(image: AssetImage('Image/soc1.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: double.infinity,),


                  const Text("hello world"
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 34.0,
                        fontFamily: "Explora",
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
             p1(),p2(), p3(),p4(), p5(),p6(),p7(),
              p8()


              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      )


     ),
   );
   }
 }
```

here is the main function

```
 const String FAVORITES_BOX="faborites_box";

  void main()  async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox(FAVORITES_BOX);

  runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: IntroScreen(
   
  )

));
}
```

and here whats been shown on the run,`Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following HiveError was thrown building NotificationListener:
Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?

```
Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
```

'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': **Failed assertion: line 258 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
PageView** PageView:file:///C:/Users/sulta/AndroidStudioProjects/quotes_app/lib/Overviewscreen.dart:47:15

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your path using path provider package? To make persistent read/writes, hive needs a directory in the emulator/device to store the data to.
Check the [Hive in Flutter Docs](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/hive_in_flutter) and make sure you follow all the steps. In short, you have to put the hive, hive_flutter and path_provider packages in your pubspec.yaml file and then have to write this line of code in your main method

```dart
await Hive.initFlutter((await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path);
```

If u need simple state management and instance manager, then i suggest [Getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get) instead of hive.

Comment: i think i have initialised flutter in this way 
const String FAVORITES_BOX="faborites_box";

void main()  async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox(FAVORITES_BOX);             is there amy wrong code here? moreover,can you please tell me whats "getApplicationDocumentDirectory()" your saying about? @Joel

Comment: and i am getting "Failed assertion: line 258 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true. The relevant error-causing widget was: PageView"....i have written the pageview code up in my question..Can you please tell me what have gone wrong?

Comment: Just add path_provider to your pubspec.yaml and then replace your Hive.initFlutter with the code given in the answer, It only solves the first error "box not found"; incase you get a error at getApplicationsDocumentsDirectory ensure you have imported path_provider at the top of your file. but I am still finding a way to fix the index errors @Arefin